# StructureMap: register generic Type as implementation of generic Interface

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, structuremap, structuremap4

Given an interface

```
public interface ISomething<TA, TB>
    where TA : class
    where TB : class, ISomeOtherInterface
{
    object SomeMethod(TSource source, TDestination destination);
}
```

And a class implementing it

```
public class Something<TA, TB> : ISomething<TA, TB>
    where TA : class
    where TB : class, ISomeOtherInterface
{
    public object SomeMethod(TA source, TB destination)
    {
        // lots of really important code.
    }
}
```

I've tried registering the implementation both via `For().Use()` and `ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing()`

```
var container = new Container();

container.Configure(config => {
    config.For(typeof(ISomething<,>))
          .Use(typeof( Something<,>));

    config.Scan(_ => {
        _.AssemblyContainingType(typeof(Something<,>));
        _.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(ISomething<,>));
    });
});
```

But to no avail; every call to `container.GetInstance<ISomething<Foo, Bar>>()` fails with a `StructureMapConfigurationException`:

> No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically determined for type 'ISomething<Foo, Bar>'
>
> There is no configuration specified for ISomething<Foo, Bar>
>
> 1.) Container.GetInstance(ISomething<Foo, Bar>)

Calling `container.WhatDoIHave()` on the very same container yields

```
ISomething<TA, TB> My.Project.Namespace Transient Something<TA, TB> (Default)
```

though. Also, calling `container.GetInstance<Something<Foo, Bar>>()` (referencing the implementation as opposed to the interface) works just fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: `ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing` does exactly that, but, unfortunately all you have as concrete type is yet another open generic. Which StructureMap will not connect to `ISomething`. Basically, you are never mapping the interface `ISomething<Foo, Bar>` to the implementation `Something<Foo, Bar>`. That's what it's actually telling you